# how do I make the display size bigger than 1920x1080 when screensharing on Mac

Tags: mac, resolution, vnc, screen-sharing

I have a main machine (Mac) and a few other machines I remote into.   Windows is great, because it stores credentials, resizes when I size the window, and goes to the full resolution of the screen - so it's seamless.

However - when I connect from Mac to Mac - the internal resolution doesn't resize when you resize the window (guessing that's just a limitation??) - even though I've saved credentials, it still wants me to go through a login screen :(. but the biggest thing

- when I first go in, it's like some ridiculous resolution, but then even if I open the display tab, show all modes, the highest mode it can go to is HD!?

How do I screen share from Mac A to Mac B and get a 4k window?  (There is no monitor plugged into Mac B).    Both Macs are on macOS Ventura, but I had the same problem in Monterey.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116809/force-the-resolution-on-a-headless-mac-mini-server

Comment: Assuming you're using the built-in VNC server to do this? Can I suggest you try NoMachine instead? You install it on both the sending device and the receiving device. When remoting in from the receiving device you can go in with the default display settings or you can choose to enter custom display settings. So when the remote window opens it will open using the display settings you specified before hitting the connect button.

Comment: https://www.nomachine.com/